# twilio message keeps getting blocked

Tags: twilio, sms, chatbot

Hello twilio newbie here, i am trying to send sms on my phone using twilio but it keeps giving me this error.

[image]

but somehow i can send sms if it is a single character string.

[image]

Comment: This could be caused by a number of reasons related to your location, carrier or the content of the message. I recommend having a look at this [support page](https://help.twilio.com/articles/360008704834-Error-30007-Message-Delivery-Carrier-Violation-when-Sending-SMS)